# Equivalent to FileInputStream in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, fileinputstream

Is there any equivalent to `FileInputStream` in J2ME?

Answer (score 9):

You should use FileConnection from JSR 75. Here is a short example of using file connection for reading file:

```
public void showFile(String fileName) {
   try {
      FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)
         Connector.open("file:///CFCard/" + fileName);
      if(!fc.exists()) {
         throw new IOException("File does not exist");
      }
      InputStream is = fc.openInputStream();
      byte b[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = is.read(b, 0, 1024);
      System.out.println
         ("Content of "+fileName + ": "+ new String(b, 0, length));
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
}
```

Please take a look [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, the FileConnection and it's getInputStream method will are the closest you will get to a FileInputStream. Here's a quick tutorial with source code:

http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/file-connection-using-j2me-api-jsr-75.html

You will find more information on this page:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?143733-How-to-test-file-reading-writing-and-web-server-app-in-emulator

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with files in the JAR file, then have a look at getResourceAsStream method, the device does not need to have JSR 75 to use it.